# Opencv remap returns squeezed image rather than slightly offsetted

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, scipy, opticalflow

I have a "distort.png" image in which the "R,G" Channels holding motion vectors (Original Position offsetted by 10 pixels) I'm using `remap` to transform the image into the new location with the following snippet but I get a weirdly squeezed image instead a translated one. Any thoughts?

```
import cv2

distort = cv2.imread(r"D:\distort.png").astype(np.float32)
src = cv2.imread(r"D:\taj.png")

map_x = distort[:, :, 1].copy()
map_y = distort[:, :, 2].copy()

remapped_image = cv2.remap(src, map_x, map_y, interpolation=cv2.INTER_LINEAR)

cv2.imshow('Original Image', remapped_image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

However the image seems to be distorted:

[image]

and supposed to look like this (translated by 10pixels in x and y):

[image]

Here is the source image "taj.png"

[image]

And the source distort (motion vector) file

[image]

Comment: Your R,G vectors are likely forward transform. But remap expects inverse transform images.

Comment: Ah is there an easy way to take the inverse of the distort image? I'll be getting those images in it's current shape

Comment: I don't know. Not sure if it makes sense to just reverse the vector directions. Likely not, though.  For equations, it is easier to invert, in many case.  Search this forum. There was one post that I recall not too long ago that reversed some equations if I recall or perhaps it was  vectors.

Comment: I figured it out... My source image had srgb color space rather than being linear....! Thanks for pointing to the direction that my source distort data is fishy

Comment: How did you reverse your data or was it already inverse direction?

Comment: I didn't, as it wasn't a linear transform, I've asked the providers to remove the s curve when generating the motion vector image

Comment: the easy way is to compute the optical flow in the same way (pull). then, at most, it's a matter of flipping the signs of all the vectors. these are not equivalent operations, they are "orthogonal". -- there is an iterative way to invert maps. this might work here. it might not. maybe non-continuous maps (as you have) will always be troublesome around discontinuities/strong gradients.